# Position third horizontal div to the bottom of other divs?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: The problem is solved, so thanks to everyone who helped!**

**Original post:**
So I am trying to put three divs next to each other (until thus far this part has been successful) with the third and last div to like go to attach to the bottom of the divs, which I have no clue how to do this.

**How can I put the third div to attach to the bottom of the middle div and stay within the container?**

To show you, I made a quick example. Something like this:

[image]

The black colour in the image is the 'body'.
The grey is a container div I put the three other divs in.
Each other box represents a div with what I want them to do and how approx. I want them to be positioned of one another.

I hope this can be done only using html and css. I would appreciate any help.

So far I have this as html for the divs:

```css
#nav,
#textarea,
#contactallpages {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
}
#containerpage {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
}
#centercontainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2%;
}
#nav {
  float: left;
  background: #aaaaaa;
  height: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 1%;
}
#textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #cccccc;
  height: 70%;
  width: 64%;
  padding: 1%;
}
#contactallpages {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 1%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerpage">
  <div id="centercontainer">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul><a href="#">1</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="#">2</a>
      </ul>
      <ul><a href="#">3</a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="textarea">
      <header>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
      </header>
      <p>
        Text text more text.
      </p>
      <p>
        And more text.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="contactallpages">
      Random small textbox
      <br>More small text.
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should lay this out is one container `div` and 3 children `div`'s set to `display: inline-block;`

Using `display: inline-block;` will position all the `div`'s next to each other and allows you to use the `vertical-align` property.

Now all you would need to do is set the proper vertical-alignment for each of the child `div`'s. You can also set the height to the container `div` (`#myPage`) and that is the height that `vertical-align` will use to determine the positioning.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
#myPage div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

#centerFold {
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#navBar, #contact{
  height: 100px;
}

#navBar {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
}
#contact {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="myPage">
  <div id="navBar">
    
    </div>
  
  <div id="centerFold">
    
    </div>
  
  <div id="contact">
    
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Is there a way to remove the small spacing between the divs?

Comment: @AmoebePanda that spacing happens to be a byproduct of `display: inline-block;` There are various ways to remove that, and you can read up on it here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Try out flexbox if you do not have too much to worry about backward compatibility. My time at the moment doesn't allow to elaborate, but the essential part would be

```
#centercontainer {display: flex}
#contactallpages {align-self: flex-end}
```

Be aware though that some prefixing will be necessary for older browsers and this is only the standards-compliant solution. It does everything you want and you can forget about floating. Adding a

```
 #textarea {flex-grow: 1}
```

would even allow the center to grow not only in height but in width also.

Comment: Thank you! With backward compatibility I assume you mean older web browsers?

Comment: Yes I do. Just check on caniuse.com for the support of flexbox. It's not too bad, though, for this purpose, since I guess it should work even in IE 10, provided you prefix.